# How can I save only one phoneId and password by SharedPreference in a button

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, autologin

I am a beginner and just learning how to create a restaurant app that allows user to login via 'member-login' and 'non-member' login. There are 3 buttons in the home screen: menu, sign in, sign up. A new member is allowed to register(sign up) and login(sign in) into the app each time, whereas a non-member can directly view the restaurant menu via (menu button) by skipping the login/registering process.

I need to capture each of the members/non-members transaction orders into firebase. So am I possible to set only 1 phoneId and password in SharedPreference for the menu button to let 'non-members' auto login into the system when they tap on the (menu button). If is possible, may i know how to implement? Thanks

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btnSignIn, btnSignUp, btnMenu;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnMenu = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnMenu);
    btnSignUp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSignUp);
    btnSignIn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSignIn);

    btnMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });

    btnMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent home = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Home.class);
            //Common.currentUser = user;
            startActivity(home);


        }
    });

    btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent signUp = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SignUp.class);
            startActivity(signUp);
        }
    });

    btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent signIn = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SignIn.class);
            startActivity(signIn);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you going to use a default phoneId  and password for non-members??

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. **Show us the code for your latest attempt** and where you got stuck. and explain why the result is not what you expected.  Edit your question to include the code, please don't add it in a comment, as it will probably be unreadable.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

It is better to show what is actually happening, rather than describing what you expect to happen.

Comment: @ParikshitChalke yes, a default phoneId and password for all non-members

Answer (score 0):

As you are beginner, remember following points about data storage in android :

**1) When to use shared preferences ->**

*If you have only one value for your entity to hold.*

e.g Now in your case you will have only one user per each application. Hence you can store your user name,password and other information in shared preferences.

**2) When to use SQLite Database ->**

*If you have more than one value for your entity to hold.*

e.g In your case, you can use SQLite to store user orders.

**Solution to your problem :**

1) Create **Constant.java** which will hold your default phoneID and password.

```
public static final String DEFAULT_PHONE_ID = "your_default_id";
public static final String DEFAULT_PASSWORD = "your_default_password";
```

2) Create **AppPreferences.java** which will save and retrieve your preferences.

```
    public class AppPreferences {
            // Class variables
                private Context context;
                private static SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
                private static SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
                private int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

     // Define your preferences key
     private static final String USER_PHONE = "user_id";
     private static final String USER_PASSWORD = "user_password";

        private AppPreferences(Context context) {
                this.context = context;
                sharedPreferences = this.context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
                if (sharedPreferences != null)
                {
                    editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                }
            }   

//Store userPhoneId
         private void setUserPhoneId(String userId){
         String TAG = "AppPreferences : setUserId";
        try
        {
            editor.putString(USER_PHONE, userId);
            editor.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e);
        }
}

// Get userPhoneId
public String getUserPhoneId(){
  return sharedPreferences.getString(USER_PHONE,"default_phone");
}

//Store userPassword
         private void setUserPasswword(String userPassword){
         String TAG = "AppPreferences : setUserPassword";
        try
        {
            editor.putString(USER_PASSWORD, userPassword);
            editor.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e);
        }
}

// Get userPassword
public String getUserPassword(){
  return sharedPreferences.getString(USER_PASSWORD,"default_phone");
}

}
```

In your activity :

```
private AppPreference appPreference;

onCreate(){

appPreference = new AppPreference(this);

}

 btnMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent home = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Home.class);
            //Here save user info to preferences
            appPreference.setUserPhoneId(Constants.DEFAULT_PHONE_ID);
            appPreference.setUserPassword(Constants.DEFAULT_PASSWORD);
            startActivity(home);


        }
    });

    btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent signUp = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SignUp.class);
            startActivity(signUp);
        }
    });

    btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent signIn = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SignIn.class);
            startActivity(signIn);
        }
    });
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: thank you, but may i know in this line `sharedPreferences = this.context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);` the **PREF_NAME** means file name or? because it appears red line

Comment: and this line `Log.e(TAG, e);` the **TAG** shows error: the logging tag can be at most 23 characters, was 26, while the **e** shows error: wrong 2nd argument type. Found 'java.lang.Exception', required 'java.lang.String'

Comment: public static final String PREF_NAME = "YourAppName"; in AppPreference.java

Comment: okay thanks, what about the `Log.e(TAG, e);` ? Is it i must decrease the logging tag's characters? and **e** is showing error too. Also, i cannot access setUserPhoneId and setUserPassword in mainActivity.java, is it i need to change them into public in AppPreferences.java?

Comment: for example, if i want to set the default phoneId as 9876543210 and password: 12345, so should i store these value into firebase first? because if just run like that, it is showing nullPointerException error

Comment: Yess make setUserPoneId and setUserPassword public.

Comment: I think this nullPointerException error is out of scope of current posted issue. You should post new question for that.